# Configure Proxy In Android x86 emulator

Tags: android, proxy, emulation

I've tried to enter a proxy into the Android x86 emulator with no success. I think the problem remains in that I don't get the authentication to enter the user/password of the dedicated prroxy (it's set up using squid).

You can find the screenshots in case you know how to fix it:

1-Before entering the proxy the Internet works with no problem.

2-Entering the proxy in the emulator.

3-After entering the proxy, Internet doesn't work.

http://postimg.org/image/fd9oqu4rx/

Thanks!